# Objective C constant string implicit conversion?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have noticed from the llvm source code that the compiler supports the flag:

```
-fconstant-string-class=CLASSNAME
```

If this flag is not present, the compiler appears to default to NSConstantString.

Upon inspection of Apple's Foundation Library, NSConstantString inherits from NSSimpleCString which provides the required ivars to enable ObjC Constant String behaviour. This in turn is a child class of NSString.

However, in normal ObjC code, the following is perfectly legal:

```
NSString *anNSString = @"This is an NSConstantString?";
```

This seems fine (NSConstantString is the child class), except:

1) The data of a constant string should be funnelled into the ivars declared in NSSimpleCString, which are not available to an NSString.

2) NSString's iteration methods suggest it is built on arrays of unichars. This means there must be some conversion from NSConstantString's chars to NSString's unichars.

As operator overloading is not possible in Objective C, how/where could this conversion take place? Is there some code generation trickery going on here? Or have I missed something more obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the only place in the framework you'll find that the class you're dealing with is not the class you're expecting. As Objective-C is duck-typed, there doesn't even need to be an inheritance relationship between the classes (although this would be desirable to let `isKindOfClass:` work correctly).

The practice of using a "front class" as an interface and a bunch of "private classes" for the implementation is elevated to a pattern in the Cocoa framework. This concept is called a "class cluster", and most Foundation classes have their own cluster. Since they all share the same public interface, everything works just like you would expect. As far as those are concerned, the front classes themselves should probably be considered abstract (even though the compile-time concept of an abstract class doesn't exist in Objective-C).

For instance, both `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` become `NSCFArray` once you hit the run button. Another case of blatant duck typing: last time I checked, when you call a method that deals with paths on a `NSString` (for example `stringByAppendingPathComponent:`), you get an instance of the `NSPathStore2` class, even though the documentation says it returns a `NSString`.

I don't see how `NSConstantString`'s ivars could be of matter to `NSString` so long as all relevant methods are implemented/overridden in `NSConstantString`. As for the conversion itself, there aren't that many public access points to `unichar`s: by my count, only 5 `NSString` methods use `unichar`s, so any required conversion could easily be done there.

**EDIT** I went a little deeper and found out `NSString` declares no ivar, leaving absolute discretion to its subclasses as far as storage is concerned. `NSSimpleCString` declares `char* bytes` and `int numBytes`; `NSConstantString` adds no ivar. Both classes implement/override `unichar` access methods.

Comment: Nice answer. To clarify a bit: `NSString` doesn't care about its ivars, even internally... all its functionality goes through the primitive methods `length` and `characterAtIndex:`. So long as its own code and any other classes that use it respect that contract, `NSConstantString` can implement those methods however it likes and still interoperate.

Comment: you may feel some discomfort and/or disorientation at first, but it will pass in time. :)

Comment: Thank you so much :). Regarding your edit - how were you able to find that NSString does not declare any additional ivars? To be able to get at that kind of internal info for other classes would be rather useful..!

Comment: @PLPiper, some time ago I made a program that uses the Objective-C runtime's reflection functions to generate an appropriate header file for a class. You can grab the source [here](http://felixcloutier.com/tmp/classexplorer.zip). It does have serious memory problems in its current form, though (although nothing unfixable).

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C is a dynamic dispatch language. You're declaring the variable as `NSString*`, but it could in fact be any subclass of `NSString*`. Since all methods are dispatched dynamically (e.g. method invocation), it doesn't matter what the compiler thinks the type of the object is[1], it only matters what the object *actually* is. So in that line of code your `anNSString` variable actually contains an `NSConstantString` instead of an `NSString`.

[1]: the type affects the selector lookup process, which affects what the compiler thinks the types of the arguments should be, which affects potential warnings and implicit coercion of types. None of this is relevant here.